# Jenkins, unable to run windows batch command in parallel jobs

Tags: jenkins, iar

I have several build jobs with separate workspaces building separate modules with iarbuild from a windows batch command in Jenkins. If I run each of these jobs separately it builds just fine, but if I try to run two different jobs using iarbuild in parallel (started within 10 sec from each other) at least one of the builds will fail with just "Build aborted" message.

If I run the same two builds in parallel directly from the windows command prompt in their respective Jenkins workspace they will build just fine. It is only in Jenkins there is a problem to build in parallel.

Does anyone know what could cause this problem?

Do the windows batch command in Jenkins share resources between build jobs?

Comment: I have had multiple builds using windows batch commands running at the same time, so my first guess is that the issue is not in Jenkins.  You might want to try running a couple of simple batch commands that just do something like `sleep 120` and see if that works.

Comment: I think it is the specific combination of iarbuild and windows batch command. I know that iarbuild is unable to run in parallel, that is why I'm wondering if some resources are shared between jobs when running windows batch commands.

Comment: If you do find something that needs to be exclusive, you might want to look at the [Jenkins Exclusion Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Exclusion-Plugin).  I've used it to prevent simultaneous access to a shared resource during the unit-testing for some of our builds.

Comment: The exclusion plugin could be fine as a workaround. Hopefully I can get IAR to solve the real problem.

Comment: The new version of iarbuild (6.50.3) solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new version of iarbuild (6.50.3) solved the problem